# How to remove characters after dot in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set something like this.

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~product_name,   ~id,      
  "xyz.com",         1,  
  "bkrk.de",         4,
)
```

I want to remove the characters after the dot, so the desired output would be like this:

````
df_A <- tribble(
  ~product_name,   ~id,      
  "xyz",         1,  
  "bkrk",         4,
)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_A = mutate(df_A, product_name = sub('\\..*', '', product_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_A %>% mutate(product_name = str_remove(product_name, '\\..*'))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  product_name    id
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 xyz              1
2 bkrk             4
```